# How to set header to the C# web application

Tags: c#

I want to set a x-rate-limit header to my web application which written in C#, but I don't know how to do that. Could anyone help me on that?

Comment: please add more information about your project as what framework are you using? which .net?

Comment: I am using .Net core

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET Core, this can be done in Configure (class Startup) with middleware:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        // Set what you want
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Referrer-Policy", "no-referrer");
        // Important, without this line you create a "short circuit" to terminate your request.
        await next();
    });
    // Other stuff
}
```